# ¿Cómo hago para que cada vez que elimine un registro de un fichero binario el resto se corran una posición?

Tags: java, java-8, binario

Estoy haciendo un programa en **Java 8** que lee de un fichero txt una lista de alumnos y los escribe en un fichero binario utilizando el **patrón DAO**. La cosa es que necesito que cada vez que se borre un alumno del fichero binario, el resto de registros que están por debajo **se muevan una posición para arriba** y la posición que ocupaban se borre.

Entonces, mi método funciona perfectamente salvo con el **último registro** que haya en el fichero binario. No he incluido ningún flag en el fichero binario para los alumnos porque el ejercicio, en principio, es sin flags.

```
@Override
public void delete(Integer i) {
    /*  Borra un registro del fichero binario partiendo de 
        un identificador dado. 
    */
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
    try {
        fileChannel.position(0);
        while (fileChannel.read(buf) != -1) {
            buf.flip();

            //leer alumno
            int size = buf.getInt();
            byte[] alumnoBytes = new byte[size];
            buf.get(alumnoBytes);
            Alumno alumno = (Alumno) deserialize(alumnoBytes);

            //comprobar si su id coincide con el del alumno que se quiere borrar
            if ((int) i == (int) alumno.getNumExp()) {
                buf.clear();

                    //mover el resto de alumnos por debajo una posición hacia arriba 
                    //sobreescribiendo el alumno que se quiere borrar por el siguiente alumno del fichero binario 
                    while (fileChannel.read(buf) != -1) {

                        buf.flip();

                        //leer alumno del buffer
                        size = buf.getInt();
                        alumnoBytes = new byte[size];
                        buf.get(alumnoBytes);
                        Alumno al = (Alumno) deserialize(alumnoBytes);

                    //guardar el alumno en el buffer
                    buf.clear();
                    buf.putInt(serialize(al).length);
                    buf.put(serialize(al));

                    //rellenar el espacio sobrante con bytes a 0
                    while (buf.position() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        byte b = 0;
                        buf.put(b);
                    }

                    //escribir el alumno una posición más arriba de la que ocupa
                    buf.flip();
                    fileChannel.write(buf, fileChannel.position() - (BUFFER_SIZE * 2));

                    //llenar la posición que ocupaba con bytes a 0
                    buf.clear();
                    while (buf.position() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        byte b = 0;
                        buf.put(b);
                    }

                    buf.flip();
                    fileChannel.write(buf, fileChannel.position() - (BUFFER_SIZE));
                    buf.clear();
                }
            }

            buf.clear();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    }
}
```

Os dejo también el **método save(Alumno a)** que guarda los alumnos en el fichero por si lo necesitáis. El **tamaño del buffer** está almacenado en la variable **BUFFER_SIZE** y tiene un valor de **600 bytes**. La clase alumno también os la dejo más abajo =)

```
@Override
public void save(Alumno a) {
    try {

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

        //poner el alumno pasado como parámetro en el buffer
        buf.clear();
        buf.putInt(serialize(a).length);
        buf.put(serialize(a));

        //rellenar el espacio sobrante con 0
        while (buf.position() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            byte b = 0;
            buf.put(b);
        }

        //escribir en el fichero binario
        buf.flip();
        fileChannel.write(buf);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Alumno implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 10L;

public enum Ciclo {
    ASIR, DAW, DAM, SMR
};
Integer numExp;
String nombre, apellido1, apellido2;
Date fechaNac;
Ciclo ciclo;

public Alumno(Integer numExp, String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, Date fechaNac, Ciclo ciclo) {
    this.numExp =  numExp;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
    this.ciclo = ciclo;
}

public Integer getNumExp() {
    return numExp;
}

public void setNumExp(Integer numExp) {
    this.numExp = numExp;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno{" + "numExp=" + numExp + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido1=" + apellido1 + ", apellido2=" + apellido2 + ", fechaNac=" + fechaNac + ", ciclo=" + ciclo + '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirviese, lo solucione de esta manera:

***EDIT***: mejora del código

```
   @Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        List<Alumno> listaAlumnos = getAll();
        int indice = 0;
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

        try {

            //almacenar en qué indice de la lista se posiciona el alumno
            for (Alumno listaAlumno : listaAlumnos) {
                if ((int) listaAlumno.getNumExp() == (int) id) {
                    indice = listaAlumnos.indexOf(listaAlumno);
                }
            }

            //si es el último alumno posicionado en la lista
            if (indice == (listaAlumnos.size() - 1)) {
                fileChannel.position(0);
                //llenar la posición que ocupaba con bytes a 0
                buf.clear();
                while (buf.position() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                    byte b = 0;
                    buf.put(b);
                }

                //escribe en la última posición del fichero
                buf.flip();
                fileChannel.write(buf, fileChannel.position() + (BUFFER_SIZE * indice));
                buf.clear();
            } else {

                //posicionarse en el alumno que se quiere borrar
                fileChannel.position(BUFFER_SIZE * (indice + 1));
                while (fileChannel.read(buf) != -1) {

                    //escribir el alumno siguiente una posición más arriba de la que ocupa
                    buf.flip();
                    fileChannel.write(buf, fileChannel.position() - (BUFFER_SIZE * 2));

                    //llenar la posición que ocupaba con bytes a 0
                    buf.clear();
                    while (buf.position() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        byte b = 0;
                        buf.put(b);
                    }

                    //escribir 0 en la posicion que antes ocupaba el alumno
                    buf.flip();
                    fileChannel.write(buf, fileChannel.position() - BUFFER_SIZE);
                    buf.clear();
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```